# My Rails Controller works and will render the updated JSON properly, but it will NOT make any changes to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a project with a React frontend and Rails backend server. The fetch from the frontend hits the Rails controller properly, and every action in the controller is hit properly. The model in question, `player`, is EDITED properly because its new attributes are sent back to the frontend fetch, however NOTHING is saved to the database, no new row is added to the table if a model needs to be created, and no values are changed if the model is just edited. The controller only has this one action so far, and it looks like this...

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

    def update_or_create
        @player = Player.create_or_find_by(name: player_params[:name])
        puts @player
        puts @player.name
        @player.update(class_type: player_params[:class], lvl: player_params[:lvl], atk: player_params[:atk], sAtk: player_params[:sAtk], def: player_params[:def], sDef: player_params[:sDef], spd: player_params[:spd], hp: player_params[:hp], move_distance: player_params[:move_distance])
        @player.save
        render json: @player
    end

    private
    def player_params
        params.require(:player).permit(:name, :inv_hash, :lvl, :name, :class, :atk, :def, :sAtk, :sDef, :spd, :hp, :move_distance)
    end
end
```

My only thought is that maybe there could be an issue with `Player.create_or_find_by` but even that doesn't make too much sense, as both `puts` statements show what they should, as does the JSON. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `@player.update!(...)` see if you have any validation errors.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much! @razvans

Comment: You are welcome ! FYI, if you do `.update` you don't need to do `.save` after that.

Comment: I was just using it as a double measure, I thought maybe `update` itself was just maybe having an issue. It turns out I forgot about a migration I left for a feature I decided to remove and it was gukking everything up